# XOR file byte by byte, save output in ASCII?

Tags: python, encryption, xor

I want to read a file character by character and XOR each byte with `172`, then save as a new file.

I've made the following:

```py
b = bytearray(open('in.txt', 'rb').read())
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i] ^= 0xAC # XOR byte with 172
open('out.txt', 'wb').write(b)
```

Trying it on a sample text file:

```
ïÃÂËÞÍØÙÀÍØÅÃÂß
```

I end up with garbage:

```
oo/o.o'o2o!o4o5o,o!o4o)o/o.o3
```

The expected output is instead:

```
Congratulations
```

Doing this by hand, I get an expected output:

```
str(chr(0xEF ^ 0xAC)) # 'C', 'ï' XOR 172 = 67, 67 to ASCII is 'C'
str(chr(0xC3 ^ 0xAC)) # 'o'
str(chr(0xC2 ^ 0xAC)) # 'n'
...
```

But trying to automate it generates nonsense. Why doesn't it correctly work and how can I get my expected output?

Comment: `ï` has the codepoint 172, but files don't contain codepoints, they contain code units from a specific encoding. If your file is in UTF-8 (which is likely) `ï` is encoded as two bytes 0xc3 0xaf, which XOR to 0x6f and 0x03, or `0` and `\x03`. Which also explains all your `o`: all your characters are in the upper range of [128, 256[ so their leading byte is 0xc3, which xor'd with 172 yields `o`. The bit between Os is the value of the xor'd continuation byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file `in.txt` doesn't use single-byte character encoding [Windows-1254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254) as you expect but perhaps multibyte [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).